# Integrating sonar cloud for code analysis of SAP Commerce hybris using azure devops pipeline

Tags: java, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sap-commerce-cloud, sonarcloud

I am trying to integrate sap commerce 2211 with sonar cloud (paid version) using azure devops pipeline. I have successfully created connection between devops and sonar cloud using generated token from sonar cloud. I am also able to configure prepare sonar analysis step in yaml using connection but unable to find how to start the analysis of code quality and junit coverage report. Please help.

I am done with the following steps

- Prepared connection successfully.
- Configure sonar cloud analysis.

**Failing at this point**

- Tried to run ant sonar but not able to publish report.

Comment: You could check the [sample](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/blob/master/sonar-scanner-ant/ant-coverage/README.md), add `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths` to your build.xml, after the coverage report generated, use task `SonarCloudAnalyze@1` and `SonarCloudPublish@1` to publish the results to SonarCloud.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am looking solution more specific to SAP hybris integration with sonar cloud. SAP hybris have the specific ant targets.